# When debugging JQuery Ajax with firefox developer edition the execution never reaches the success or error functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

When debugging JQuery Ajax with firefox developer edition the execution never reaches the success or error functions even when breakpoints are set. I tried  async:false, based on related post. What is wrong?  It reaches up to data.

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/myurl/',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {
            mydata: my_data
        },
        success: function(result) { //we got the response
            alert('Successfully called');
        },
        error: function(jqxhr, status, exception) {
            alert('Exception:', exception);
        }
    })
```

I removed async:false, now it reaches success and error but none of their alerts is executed.  if it is not a success should error alert execute?

UPDATE: it says,
$.ajax is not a function

but jquery is loaded.

Comment: What event are you running this code under? It would help to see a more complete sample of your JS

Comment: Async is a bad practice unless it is absolutely required. It locks up the user's browser til its done.  Also, have you made sure your libs are loaded (jquery in this case) and my_data is properly defined.  if my_data is an object, make sure it is serialized (JSON.stringify({mydata:my_data})

Comment: @Bindrid You do mean `async:false` is bad practice, right?

Comment: @David  Yes, thanks for pointing my mistake